# Downloading libsnappy-dev - shared object file does not show up, symlink broken

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, debian

I did the following to download the libsnappy static/shared libraries in order to use it in a non-root context with my projects (I will pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` later for .so's). I did the following to extract the package:

```
❯ apt-get download libsnappy-dev
❯ ar x libsnappy-dev_1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
❯ tar -xf data.tar.xz
❯ ls
control.tar.gz  data.tar.xz  debian-binary  libsnappy-dev_1.1.3-3_amd64.deb  usr
❯ ls -l usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
total 86K
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx users 43630 Mar 19  2016 libsnappy-shared.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx users 42614 Mar 19  2016 libsnappy.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx users    18 Mar 19  2016 libsnappy.so -> libsnappy.so.1.3.0
```

Unfortunately, there is no `libsnappy.so.1.3.0` in this directory, so this shared object file symlink doesn't resolve correctly. Where did the actual .so file go? Did I miss a step?

Comment: The library itself is provided by the corresponding runtime package (`libsnappy1v5` I think)

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! I wasn't aware that there is a runtime package. Could you explain what types of packages there are? I know of the minimal install (without -dev), and with -dev, but am not familiar with other types. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it :)